SVG transparency breaks PDF/A compatibility
Currently, I'm using mPDF to create PDF/A files in PHP.
SVGs have a transparent background by default. But this breaks compatibility to PDF/A. When validation such a PDF file using veraPDF, I get an error, saying "A Group object with an S key with a value of Transparency shall not be included in a form XObject. A Group object with an S key with a value of Transparency shall not be included in a page dictionary"

I've tried to a add a rect to the SVG (like it is stated here) but have not had luck.
Is there a solution to remove this transparency but still being able to use SVGs?
EDIT: I'm using simple FontAwesome icons as SVG, for example the globe. Looking at the SVG code I can't find any opacity or transparency style in it.
EDIT 2: I've uploaded a sample of a SVG and a resulting PDF file created with mPDF.

As commented by K J: please add a minimal example of the converted SVG/HTML. "Vector transparency" - (so no background or a shape on top of another) can usually be converted pretty well in mPDF. Things get tricky when fills or strokes are semi-transparent or <mask> definitions are involved ... or if there are any transparent or  filter affected elements stacked on top or under of your SVG. You may also check your SVG color definitions (any rgba values?)

I'm using "simple" SVG icons from FontAwesome, which have no transparency (see edited post)

OK, I think there was a misunderstanding. Used SVG and created PDF are available for download now. Most basic example.

OMG, thanks for your investigation. Finally, it should become a PDF/A-3, but it would be the same problem there. I.e. thanks for finding the exact code lines, I stopped at /Image/Svg.php. Even it's a workaround, your solution would fit my needs, so I'll extend (else modify) the code. Please make an answer of your approach, so I can accept it. Thanks a ton.

mPDF currently expects SVG will be transparent thus includes the following in its code.
// Required for SVG transparency (opacity) to work
            $this->writer->object();
            $this->writer->write('<</Type /Group')
            $this->writer->write('/S /Transparency');

For PDF/A-1B (in particular) that last line is not acceptable.
Vera accepts the file if we blank out the /S/Transparency such that this is a pass ## 0 obj <</Type/Group                >> endobj this would be a SIMPLE temporary workaround to keep EXACTLY the same number of bytes, to ensure no other fail.

The "simple" solution (if needing just 1B compatibility) is build a mPDF variant without that line from the SVG handler and any other of the few similar settings.
Seen here https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ampdf%2Fmpdf%20%2FTransparency&type=code
